# how to get the filename from the mentioned list

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I am new to linux and/or scripting, so bear with me. I want a script which can get the files for a Linux directory. here what I tried for getting the filename.

> `for NAME in $(ls -1 *.wav /some/path | cut -d "/" -f3 | cut -d "-" -f1-5)`

if the filename contains -IN or -OUT then they will be ***sox -m*** and after that ***mv*** to another directory but if the some other files then it will be just ***mv***

for the reference, filenames be like

> 1030-04-06-2015-1433414216.wav
>   1030-04-06-2015-1433414318.wav
>   1030-04-06-2015-1433414440.wav
>   1043-21-05-2015-1432207256.wav
>   1043-21-05-2015-1432207457.wav
>   1046-20-05-2015-1432137944.wav
>   1046-20-05-2015-1432138015.wav
>   1046-20-05-2015-1432138704.wav
>   1431709157.93900.0-in.wav
>   1431709157.93900.0-out.wav
>   1431709157.93900.1-in.wav
>   1431709157.93900.1-out.wav
>   1431710008.94059.0-in.wav
>   1431710008.94059.0-out.wav
>   1431710008.94059.1-in.wav
>   1431710008.94059.1-out.wav
>   1431710008.94059.1.wav
>   1431710008.94059.2.wav
>   1431713190.94698.2-in.wav
>   1431713190.94698.2-out.wav
>   1431713190.94698.2.wav
>   1431721107.96010.0-in.wav
>   1431721107.96010.0-out.wav
>   1431721107.96010.1.wav

Comment: Have you tried writing anything for this so far? Show us your attempts if you have.

Comment: title says: `how to get the filename from the mentioned list`, where's that mentioned list? in a file? or you just want every file in a directory? or may be with .wav extension? You should at least be specific and clear about your requirements, if all you are gonna do is request code from others....

Comment: @EtanReisner, tried few things with ***FIND*** and ***CUT*** as I want the ***BASENAME*** but as you can see the I have already "-" in all the files.

Comment: @Jahid I have a ***directory*** having wave files in it with filename as shown in my question.

Comment: Show us at least of your attempts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='(.*)(-out|-in)(.txt)'
for file in *.txt;do
# $file is the full path to the file
  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]];then
  #filename in this block contains -in or -out 
    filename="${file##*\/}"
    inorout="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    extension="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    filenamewithoutextension="${filename%.*}"
    filenamewithoutioroutorextension="${filenamewithoutextension/%$inorout/}"
    filenamewithoutiorout="${filenamewithoutioroutorextension}$extension"
    echo "$filename" "$inorout" "$extension" "$filenamewithoutextension" "$filenamewithoutiorout" "$filenamewithoutioroutorextension"
    #do something here sox-m mv or whatever
  else
  #filename in this block doesn't contain -in or -out
    echo "do something else"
  fi
done
```

---

Explanation:

`"${file##*\/}"` is the string left by cutting `*/` from  `$file` i.e the basename (filename).

`"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` is the second captured group from the pattern matching done by `[[ $file =~ $regex ]]` i.e `-in` or `-out`

`"${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"` is the third captured group i.e `.wav`.

`"${filename%.*}"` is the string left by cutting `.*` from `$file` i.e filename without `.wav`

---

Resources you should check on:

1. [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
2. [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)
3. [Bash Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables)

Comment: Thanks @Jahid. but as you may know, what I want is, the BASIC filename without ***-IN/-OUT*** so that I can MIX both IN/OUT and NAME the output BASIC filename.

Comment: @AamirAhmed I have added two other variables: `filenamewithoutiorout` and `filenamewithoutioroutorextension`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
>cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

destination="./DEST"

# Loop over every file
for file in "${@}" ; do
  # If it is "-in", then sox
  if [[ "${file}" =~ "-in" ]] || [[ "${file}" =~ "-out" ]] ; then
    printf "sox -m ${file}; "
  fi
  echo "mv ${file} ${destination}"
done
```

When run, I get the following output.

```
>../test.sh *
mv 1030-04-06-2015-1433414216.wav ./DEST
mv 1030-04-06-2015-1433414318.wav ./DEST
mv 1030-04-06-2015-1433414440.wav ./DEST
mv 1043-21-05-2015-1432207256.wav ./DEST
mv 1043-21-05-2015-1432207457.wav ./DEST
mv 1046-20-05-2015-1432137944.wav ./DEST
mv 1046-20-05-2015-1432138015.wav ./DEST
mv 1046-20-05-2015-1432138704.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431709157.93900.0-in.wav; mv 1431709157.93900.0-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431709157.93900.0-out.wav; mv 1431709157.93900.0-out.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431709157.93900.1-in.wav; mv 1431709157.93900.1-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431709157.93900.1-out.wav; mv 1431709157.93900.1-out.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431710008.94059.0-in.wav; mv 1431710008.94059.0-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431710008.94059.0-out.wav; mv 1431710008.94059.0-out.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431710008.94059.1-in.wav; mv 1431710008.94059.1-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431710008.94059.1-out.wav; mv 1431710008.94059.1-out.wav ./DEST
mv 1431710008.94059.1.wav ./DEST
mv 1431710008.94059.2.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431713190.94698.2-in.wav; mv 1431713190.94698.2-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431713190.94698.2-out.wav; mv 1431713190.94698.2-out.wav ./DEST
mv 1431713190.94698.2.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431721107.96010.0-in.wav; mv 1431721107.96010.0-in.wav ./DEST
sox -m 1431721107.96010.0-out.wav; mv 1431721107.96010.0-out.wav ./DEST
mv 1431721107.96010.1.wav ./DEST
mv DEST ./DEST
```

If you want to execute the commands, simply cut and paste these lines into a shell, or modify the bash script to execute these commands rather than print them.

Comment: with your script, it is getting the ***/some/path/filename.wav*** as I only want the ***BASENAME*** from the source directory.